# How can I see the track changes on the right side of the Word file?

Tags: microsoft-word, tracking

Attached is the snap-shot of a Microsoft Word file with track changes as on:

[image]

In the yellow circle I have highlighted the changes that are done already. But when I do the editing in the Word file, there are no such notes coming automatically to the right side of the word file. What setting need to be changed?

Comment: Have you enabled modification tracking? It's in the Revision tab in the Ribbon (Office 2007 and higher).

Comment: What version of Office are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I just struggled with this myself, going from Word 2016 on MacOS, where the changes were tracked by default on the right side, as you point out, to Word 2016 on Windows, where this was no longer the case for the same file.

What I discovered, was that in addition to enabling *Track Changes* in the *Review* section, I also had to:

1. Choose *All Markup* in the dropdown menu to the right, and
2. in the *Show Markup* -> *Baloons* menu below, choose *Show Revisions in Ballons*.

Answer (score 0):

To track changes in Microsoft Word you need to turn on "Track Changes" option :

- By pressing CTRL+SHIFT+E
- Via the interface in review section

[image]

Comment: You can also turn Track Changes on/off in the Status Bar.